# Как заставить работать Blink на pic12f629 в MPLAB X (C)?

Tags: c, микроконтроллеры, pic

Пытаюсь сделать хотя бы просто,чтобы светодиод горел, но почему то пик выдаёт 0.02-0.05 вольт + если палецем прикоснуться к плюсу светодиода он немного загорается. Что мешает пику выдать полные 5 вольт на светодиод?
Вот код:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <pic12f629.h>

void main(void) {
 GIE = 0;
 CMCON = 0x07; // отключение компараторов
 TRISIO = 0b00001000;
 GPIO = 0b00000000;
  while(1){
   GPIO2 =1;
  }
}
```